SharePoint Provider Hosted APP + Invalid JWT Token error even after updating the Expired Client secret key
Provider Hosted app with Mutli Tenant Scenario.
I have an expired client secret key for my SharePoint Provider Hosted App.
I have replaced the expired client secret key using power shell script and also removed the expired keys from the vault.
Still my app is not working and giving me the error for the "Invalid JWT Token".
I have debugged my app service in the azure, and conclude that it is getting the new client secret in the TokenHelper.cs file.
Do I need to wait for 12 hours or am I missing somethig in here?
